# Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms not firing add_endRequest

Tags: webforms

I have recently added [Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms/5.0.0) and since that moment add_endRequest aren't being fired and I have a lot of things that are based on this.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the javascript that uses `add_endRequest` is after the scriptmanager. (the scriptmanager i'm using is from the ajax control toolkit.)